# C: switch with cases to determine type of output msg (stored in char)

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

I'm a bit of a newbie but I've spent quite a bit of time trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here..

I'm using Turbo C and some of the time the output message I get is actually a part of the Borland Turbo C text, so it seems that the text is not being stored in the char losemsg..

```
void lose(int d) //Different messages for different deaths
{
  char *losemsg; //Lose message
  setcolor(4);
  settextstyle(0,0,1); //Set font size
switch(d)
{
case '1': losemsg="STOP HURTING THE WALL!"; //Hitting the wall
break;
case '2': losemsg="Like all great dictators, you've fallen...!"; //Falling
break;
case '3': losemsg="Oh well, sucks to be you...";
break;
case '4': losemsg="You've been killed by a spike, how sad..."; //Spike
break;
case '5': losemsg="You've been hit by something that defies gravity!";
break;
case '6': losemsg="There is no lifeguard, you've drowned!"; //Drowning
break;
}
outtextxy(100,150,losemsg);
delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, except if the input value is outside `'1'`-`'6'`. In the latter case, the behaviour of your code in undefined (you are displaying the string pointed to by an uninitialized pointer).

Comment: Well it shouldn't be a problem as I'm only calling the function with 1-6, the problem was using "case '1'" rather than "case 1".

Comment: @user2202998: Well, `1` is outside `'1'-'6'`, so it was exactly right! ;)

Comment: Good point, thanks! I was used to using the switch to compare characters i got from getch, in which case I'd use the ''

Answer (score 0):

```
...
case '6': losemsg="There is no lifeguard, you've drowned!"; //Drowning
break;

default: /* If you enter not 1..6 then it simply ends wothout strange behaviour. */
break;
}
```

You've created a pointer named *losemsg*. This pointer must point to/on some variable.

If the goal is to: 1) Enter the num from 1 to 6. 2) Depending on the entered num, it will print some string. Am I right? 
If it's so, read the following:
I think that `char` may contain 1 character. But to remember a *string* (more than 1 character) you can create 6 variables (create 6 arrays of `char` type) :

```
/* You can create them beforehead in the individual file of function */
/* (it's difficult, but it is worth it! =) ) */
char str_1; /* 1..6 */
scanf("%s", &str_1);
printf("%s", &str_1);
```

And, depending on the entered num, it will print the required string.